# Laplacian on $L^2$

Tags: analysis

how does one define the laplacian on $L^2(U)$ with $U$ open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ? I've seen a few times that it's indeed possible, but I can figure out how.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laplacian of a function $u \in L^2(U)$ is a distribution. It may be defined by $$L(\phi) = \int_U u \Delta \phi \, dx,\quad \phi \in \mathcal D(U).$$